# Navigation bar turns solid black during push to new view controller

Tags: xcode, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController. Tapping a button pushes another view controller which has the navigation bar hidden. The issue is while the animation occurs, the navigation bar for the previous view turns a solid black.

Here's the best shot I could get. (The navigation bar is white by default)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQw9U.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

instead of

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```